# How to set httr-oauth of send_message gmailr R?

Tags: r, httr

```
send_message(mime(from="you@me.com", to="any@one.com",
                  subject="hello", "how are you doing?"))
```

it will ask for authentication, if will not find `.httr-oauth` in the current working directory, is there any away to direct R to look for the file in another directory / folder.

I was told "set R option `httr_oauth_cache` to the location you want to use to cache the oauth credentials. It defaults to `.httr-oauth`, but this can be any relative or absolute file location."

I do not know how to do that, kindly provide example for illustration.